# How to get the first and last day of the last x (x = 3, 6 or 12) months in php?

Tags: php

How can I get the first and last day of the last x (I'll replace x by 3, 6 and 12) months ? I know that for the last month will be : `date("Y-n-j", strtotime("first day of previous month"));`

Comment: More information would be helpful. So if we're talking last 3 months from today, you want September, August, July, the final result being an array with 7-1-15 and 9-30-15? Or do you want the first and last day for each of those months?

Comment: of course like I said it in the question, I just need the first and last of these intervals

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime object:

```
$myDate = new \DateTime("last day of next month");
$format = $myDate->format("Y-n-d");
```

It returns: 2015-11-30

You can find `Relative Formats` here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Hope it will help you

Comment: *last day of the last x (I'll replace x by 3, 6 and 12)*  -

Comment: Show a dev where to research and they'll code for days!

Answer (score 0):

You already know that a month starts on the 1st. The `t` specifier to [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gives you the number of days in a given month. You can combine the two of those for a given month to determine the first and last day. From there, you would just need to add/subtract 3, 6, and 12 months but that exercise is up to you.

```
<?php
$first_of_this_month = date("Y-m-01");
$last_of_this_month = date("Y-m-t")
```